# How do you parse the sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

The original sentence:

> In this way, we have learned all that we know of the laws of
>   astronomy, or of the habits of the social insects, let us say.

Please let me make it simpler as below:

> In this way, we have learned all that we know of the laws of
>   astronomy.

In the above sentence, what is modified by "of the laws of astronomy"?

1. know (of the laws of astronomy)
2. that (of the laws of astronomy)
3. that we know of the laws of astronomy [i.e., we know that (of the laws of astronomy)]

Comment: 4. None of the above. The adverbial prepositional phrase is modifying the noun phrase "all that we know," in this case.

Comment: @geekahedron, thanks. I am still confusing. Do you think "all" is a determiner, an adverb, or a pronoun in this case?

Comment: It would be a pronoun, the head of the aforementioned noun phrase. Consider a simpler statement like "we learned all" and the same with the pronoun replaced, as in "we learned astronomy."

Comment: @geekahedron, if "all" is a pronoun, then "that we know" would be its attributive clause, the phrase structure is like "all (that we know)," right? If so, the sentence would be parsed as: In this way, we have learned all (that we know) of the laws of astronomy. right?

Comment: _All_ is a quantifier, and quantifiers are usually determiners (though they can float to adverbial position). In this sentence, _all_ is short for _all things_ because it's immediately followed by a relative clause _that we know of the laws of astronomy_ to denote what those things are. The _in this way_ part at the beginning is an adverb phrase that can also go at the end, as well as in several niches inside the sentence.

Comment: (I misspoke in my first response; a prepositional phrase modifying a noun phrase is of course not adverbial.)

Comment: Yes, I would consider "that we know" to be a restrictive relative (attributive) clause, and I would parse it as [ᴾᴾ [ᴺᴾ all [ᶜˡᵃᵘˢᵉ that we know Øʳᵉˡ] ] of the laws...].

Comment: I can also see an argument for [ᴺᴾ all] [ᶜˡᵃᵘˢᵉ that we know [ᴾᴾ of the laws...]] as in your first suggestion, where the PP would modify "know."

Answer (score -1):

To make parsing this sentence simpler, you can remove the cautionary "that we know of" and just say:

> In this way, we have learned all of the laws of astronomy.

The author has added the phrase "that we know of" because there is a strong possibility that we do not know **all** of the laws of astronomy. We only know "all that we know".